# JUnit test of a method using ArrayList gets a String error

Tags: java, arraylist, junit, junit4

This is the error trace I get:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: expected: java.lang.String<[{Song: title=Always artist=Blink 182}]> but was: java.util.ArrayList<[{Song: title=Always artist=Blink 182}]>
```

when I try and run this piece of code in the test case

```
assertEquals("[{Song: title=Always artist=Blink 182}]", p.getSongList());
```

`p.getSongList` is a method that returns and `ArrayList<Song>`. I've only added the one song so far but I am confused about how to change the expected output to `java.util.ArrayList` instead of `java.lang.String`. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You are comparing an `ArrayList` instance with the **string representation** of the desired output (i.e., the `String` you'd get if you run `toString()` on the output). Instead, you should just construct the actual output you're expecting.

Your question doesn't supply the code for your `Song` class, so I'm guessing it's just a POJO:

```
Song expectedSong = new Song();
expectedSong.setTitle("Always");
expectedSong.setArtist("Blink 182");
ArrayList<Song> expectedList = new ArrayList<>(1);
expectedList.add(song);
assertEquals(expectedList, p.getSongList());
```